# Scrape Content from table generated by js

Tags: javascript, python, html

I want to extract content from a table within a website that appears to be generated after the website loads using Python. Some excerpts from the html code of the website:

I believe this displays the table:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered hoverRowHand" id="contentTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="5%">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th width="10%">Date Uploaded</th>
                    <th width="10%">Survey ID</th>
                    <th width="5%">Airport ID</th>
                    <th width="20%">Airport</th>
                    <th width="10%">Survey Type</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And I believe running these scripts generates the contents for the table:

```
<script src="/global/js/nfdc-suite.js"></script>
<script src="/global/bootstrap-3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/global/js/date.js"></script>
<script src="/global/js/spin.min.js"></script>
<script src="/global/js/jquery.twbsPagination.js"></script>

<script src="/nfdcApps/include/main.js"></script>


<script src="/nfdcApps/services/publicData/uddfList-dt.js"></script>
<script src="/global/js/nfdcPublicDataTable.js"></script>
```

Simply getting the html of the website obviously does not provide any of the information I am looking for, since I believe it is first necessary to run the scripts which generate it.

Is this feasible to do with Python? Or is this something unreasonable to accomplish with Python.

Side note: If I use the "inspect element" tool in my Chrome browser I can see the content I am looking for.

Comment: You can either try to figure out how the js generates the table or use an embedded browser you control with python. This sort of open-ended question is offtopic here, though, as you probably know